# Extracting Page URL from PDF using Python

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to compile a list of URLs for a large set of PDFs I have saved using the Print -> Save as PDF function in Google Chrome. I'd like to use python to create this list. Chrome adds a link to the original page in the footer for each page of the PDF, like so:

[image]

I have tried using PyPDF but it seems unable to locate this link.

Comment: Can you provide your code that tries to find a links and an example of a file from which it fails to find one?  Does it find any links, or just miss some?

Comment: Not *all text* inside *any PDF* is *always extractable* by definition. A good test is to check if you can select and correctly copy the text out of this PDF with Adobe's canonical reference PDF reader Acrobat Reader (no worries, it is freely downloadable).

Comment: @Jongware, the link is select-able in Acrobat and the link is clickable, at least in Google Chrome.

Comment: @EricRenouf, it finds all the links except the link to the article itself. Here is an example pdf: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tmw7hv6gku51ypl/Example.pdf?dl=0 and here's the code: http://pastebin.com/Lt4ZRDVN

Comment: That URL at the bottom is no clickable when I view it in Firefox at your dropbox link there.  Perhaps Chrome is just recognizing something that looks like a URL and helping you out, but it's not really an embedded URL?